# If $(f_n)$ is a uniformly convergent sequence of Riemann Integrable functions on $[a,b]$, then the limit of integral equals the integrals of $f$

Tags: real-analysis

Proof that: If $(f_n)$ is a uniformly convergent sequence of Riemann Integrable functions on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable and:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b f_n(x)\,dx = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx $$

I am just wondering how R-integrability relates to the limit.

Comment: If they're not integrable, then we can't talk about their integrals!

Comment: From what I understood in class, for a uniformly convergent sequence with out Riemann intergability, the limit can not be "pushed inside' the integral. You could potentially have a situation where non of your sequence of functions are intergable yet still uniformly converge to f.

Comment: Hint: Use upper and lower Riemann sums, and check if the oscillation can be made small enough